# docker registry with --insecure-registry and docker 1.5

Tags: debian, docker, docker-registry

I have an issue with docker 1.5.

So, I run a private registry at myregistry:5000. 
I can push & pull from an other location (debian 7 & docker 1.4) with :

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myregistry:5000"
```

in /etc/default/docker

Now, I have a new system with docker 1.5 and debian 8, it's not working anymore.
I tried all possibilities like, `--insecure-registry=myregistry:5000` or `--insecure-registry http://myregistry:5000`

Any clue?

(Note : It works well if I stop docker and launch `docker -d --insecure-registry myregistry:5000` )

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Not yet, but I'm still working on it. While I didn't find the solution, I launch `docker -d --insecure-registry myregistry:5000` in a screen ( http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/ ). It works well for docker push & pull. Not very clean, but it does the job. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Jordan, see my answer to the topic, if it can helps you :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. I think there is a good chance that is my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can help anyone, 
I think the problem not coming from Docker, (I tried to update my registry with no success) but from `systemd` start command.

So, it's not a clean solution, but it still cleaner than launching docker in a screen.

I modify `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
and change the `ExecStart` line :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker --insecure-registry myregistry:5000 -d -H fd://
```

Then, `systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker`

And that's it. It works. I can pull & push to my distant private registry.

Comment: A better way so you can continue using `/etc/default/docker` file, is modify `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` this way: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS` adding also this line `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker` at the end of [Service section] in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue on **Debian 9** and **Docker Se 18.06.1-ce**. 
I have got an error message:

> Using default tag: latest
>   Error response from daemon: Get https://mydocker-hub:5000/v2/: http:
>   server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

You can solve the problem in different ways.

1. You can create a file (or modify) `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add into it following strings:

   ```
   { "insecure-registries": ["yourdocker-hub:5000"] }
   ```

   Restart the docker service: `service docker restart`
2. You can modify `/etc/default/docker` and edit `DOCKER_OPTS` option

   ```
   DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry yourdocker-hub:5000'
   ```

   Restart the docker service: `service docker restart`
3. Also, you can modify a file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and add `--insecure-registry yourdocker-hub:5000` to command line of service

   ```
   [Service]        
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --insecure-registry yourdocker-hub:5000
   ```

   Now you need to reload systemd manager configuration, run: `systemctl daemon-reload`
   Restart the docker service: `service docker restart`
4. You can stop the docker service and start it manually with options.

   ```
   service docker stop
   docker -d yourdocker-hub:5000
   ```

If you get an error, see your `/var/log/syslog` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use Docker 1.5 on Ubuntu Utopic 14.10 with own Docker Registry server on 5000 port. Everything works well. There are some additional options in my `/etc/default/docker` file that probably will make no sense for your situation. Just see how the local registry is enabled:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--debug --log-level=\"debug\" --dns 172.17.42.1 --insecure-registry 172.16.99.67:5000"
```

Reboot your computer after config changes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help. I still have the same issue with my clients under docker 1.5. `Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://cargo.irisa.fr:5000/v1/_ping: EOF.` I have also 2 running with docker 1.3 & docker 1.4 which are perfectly fine... Do you use the very last version of the docker registry?

Comment: @charly-m, yeah, I built my own container with registry. `docker-registry` itself installed via pip: 
`docker-registry==0.9.1
docker-registry-core==2.0.3
docker-registry-driver-elliptics==0.1.1
`