# Set Docker daemon options on Azure hosted agent

Tags: docker, azure-devops, artifactory, docker-registry

I'm messing around with Artifactory and have used the artififactory-pro docker container to get me up and running on an azure vm. I'm now trying to push a docker image to the docker-local repository within Artifactory. This is working locally but I had to change my local docker options to include the insecure-registry I set up.

To continue my POC further I want to be able to push to the artifactory docker repo using the MS hosted 'ubuntu-latest' agent with Azure pipelines but I believe I need to set the docker options on the agent to again allow the insecure regsitry as it's currently throwing the error:

```
[Error] Docker login failed for: http:/, http:.
```

How do I set the docker options on the MS hosted agent within my pipeline? I'm having to install .net-core 3.1 sdk during the pipeline so i'd like to think it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mike you cannot set docker options to allow insecure regsitry on MS hosted agent, did you tried creating your own on-premise agent?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot set docker options to allow insecure regsitry on MS hosted agent. To set insecure registry, you have to modify some docker config file. But we are restricted to modify the system files of MS hosted agent for security reason, you will get access denied error if you try to do so.

The workaround is to create your own [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) on your local machine. So that you can set the [insecure registry for docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430024/docker-registry-with-insecure-registry-and-docker-1-5) daemon on local machine.

However you can also [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click suggest a feature and choose azure devops) to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider implementing a feature to enable seting docker options on MS hosted agent.